# Use of take in drop function of persisted list

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, rust, lifetime

I am reading [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/third-drop.html), specifically the chapter about a persistent singly-linked stack.

I am having difficulty understanding use of `take` in the `drop` function.
Without it, I get the same logs in `drop`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::fmt;

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct List<T>
where
    T: fmt::Debug,
{
    head: Link<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T>
where
    T: fmt::Debug,
{
    val: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> List<T>
where
    T: fmt::Debug,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn append(&self, val: T) -> List<T> {
        List {
            head: Some(Rc::new(Node {
                val: val,
                next: self.head.clone(),
            })),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for List<T>
where
    T: fmt::Debug,
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("1 : {:?}", self);
        let mut curr_list = self.head.take();
        println!("2");
        while let Some(node) = curr_list {
            println!("3");
            match Rc::try_unwrap(node) {
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("4");
                    break;
                }
                Ok(ref mut x) => {
                    println!("5");
                    curr_list = x.next.take()
                }
            }
            println!("6");
        }
        println!("7");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = List::new().append(1).append(2);
    let _list2 = list.append(3);
    let _list3 = list.append(3);
    let _list4 = list.append(3);
    let _list5 = list.append(3);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed2fafa73cb26f0a0f92f574255df078&version=stable)

It outputs:

```
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }
2
3
4 : stopping at 1
7
1 : List { head: None }
2
7
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 3, next: Some(Node { val: 2, next: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }) }) }
2
3
5: dropping 3
6
3
4 : stopping at 2
7
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 3, next: Some(Node { val: 2, next: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }) }) }
2
3
5: dropping 3
6
3
4 : stopping at 2
7
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 3, next: Some(Node { val: 2, next: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }) }) }
2
3
5: dropping 3
6
3
4 : stopping at 2
7
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 3, next: Some(Node { val: 2, next: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }) }) }
2
3
5: dropping 3
6
3
4 : stopping at 2
7
1 : List { head: Some(Node { val: 2, next: Some(Node { val: 1, next: None }) }) }
2
3
5: dropping 2
6
3
5: dropping 1
6
7
```

The first and second `1 : List {` is because of first line in `main`, which is destroying temp lists created. The next 3 `1 : List {` are lists getting dropped in reverse order of creation. Finally the shared list of size 2 is dropped.

Even if I remove `take` from line : `curr_list = x.next.take()` and remove `ref mut` for `x` in `fn drop` I still get the same output.

What is `x` there and why does `take()` have no effects?

I earlier thought that `take` would change the original list by setting the next to `None`, but that is not possible as that will invalidate the list for other people who have references.

Implementing `drop` on Node :

```
impl<T> Drop for Node<T> where T: fmt::Debug {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Node drop : {:?}", self.val);
    }
}
```

so, Just after `Ok(ref mut x)` block, Node `x` is dropped.

Comment: Question may look long, but i believe that someone you knows Rust, should be able to answer my query easily. Please have a look.

Comment: Have you looked at [Rc::try_unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap)? It looks like you overlooked what it does.

Comment: @oli_obk-ker docs says `Returns the contained value in Ok case` : but is that `x` copy of original value in Rc ? I think its a copy. That will explain why take() has no effect. As, it modifies a copy which does not change original list. Right ?

Comment: Ok, i was wrong above. It should return Ok(original_value) when it has only one reference, which is the current one. So, then what is the difference in `curr_list = x.next` and `curr_list = x.next.take()` . second should be efficient as it makes `x.next` `None` ..

Comment: to test this i have to implement `drop` on Node.

Comment: I was expecting to see more `1: List..` but now i got that its not possible, as `next` is a `Link` not a `List`. `Link` is essentially wrapper over `Node`.

Comment: Does that mean you have figured it out or is (part of) your question still unanswered?

Comment: @trentcl i think my query was : Is `take()` important in `drop` in above program ? I now think that its not, [take](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3b29be3a84d680dd3903ac7be632892b&version=stable) and [no take](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8508e13f9d74b8cdcd434863995004d2&version=stable)

Comment: But i have understood the problem more now.